# Why am I getting an IllegalStateException when my chromedriver file is in the right place?

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I believe my chromedriver file is in the right place (blurred 's....' let's call this text "sName"):
[image]

And this is me getting the error:
[image]

What I don't understand is, why does it work fine in all my other files? For example, in the left Package Explorer, you can see the 'section4' project where I've made files that let me go to flipkart.com and view the powerbanks they have for sale. The 'section4' project works just fine and I believe it relies on the same chromedriver as well.

flipKart.java:

```
package section4flipkart;

import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import utils.WaitUtility;


public class flipKart {

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    String url = "https://www.flipkart.com/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/sName/eclipse-workspace/libs/chromedriver.exe");
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(url);
    }
    
    public void mouseHover() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2doB4z']")).click();
        
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text()='Electronics']")));
        
        WebElement electronicsLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Electronics']"));
        
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(electronicsLink).build().perform();
        
        WaitUtility.waitTillElementVisible(driver, By.xpath("//a[text()='Powerbank']"), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        WebElement powerbankLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Powerbank']"));
        action.moveToElement(powerbankLink).click().build().perform();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flipKart fp = new flipKart();
        fp.invokeBrowser();
        fp.mouseHover();
    }
}
```

WaitUtility.java file:

```
package utils;


import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class WaitUtility {
    public static void waitTillElementVisible(WebDriver driver, By by, Duration timeoutInSeconds) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
        
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    }
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working. I've tried opening terminal, navigating to the chromedriver file directory and running:

```
spctl --add --label 'Approved' chromedriver
```

but not sure if that made a difference. When trying this I changed

```
"/Users/sName/eclipse-workspace/libs/chromedriver.exe"
```

to

```
"/Users/sName/eclipse-workspace/libs/chromedriver"
```

but still getting the ' "chromedriver" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified' popup that my mac is giving.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved it thanks to chatgpt lol.

Here's what I did:

1. i removed ".exe" off the file extension
2. after I was getting the ' "chromedriver" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified' popup, I did this (copied from chatgpt):

- Open the "System Preferences" on your macOS.
- Click on "Security & Privacy."
- In the "General" tab, you should see a message saying "chromedriver" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer.
- Click on the "Allow Anyway" button next to the message.
  You might be prompted to enter your username and password to authorize the change. Provide the required information.
- Try running your code again, and it should now be able to execute the Chromedriver without the verification error.